# Converting Decimal to binary using only the basics

Tags: c++

I have to write a program that converts a decimal number between (1.0 - 99.99) into binary. My teacher said We can ONLY use the things we learned in class so far, witch include: Loops, input/output files, strings, if/else, cmath, and user defined functions. Ive started to program how  to convert an integer to binary first before taking on the decimal. I am able to calculate the binary value but I am spitting out my binary in reverse order. So my teacher said to send the remainders(eg: bit values) to a file and read them as a string. Which is were I am now. Still with the same problem. How do I print these values from a string in reverse order?
My attempt so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
int number;
int remainder;
string bitValues;
ofstream outFile;
ifstream inFile;

//inFile.open("C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\BinaryIn.txt"); // pay no mind to this.
outFile.open("C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\BinaryOut.txt");

cout << "Enter a integer to be converted to binary: ";
cin >> number;

while(number != 0)
{
    remainder = number % 2; 
    outFile << remainder << " "; // I send it to the outFile
    number /= 2;
}
outFile.close(); // I close because I need to read from it now.

inFile.open("C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\BinaryOut.txt"); //I did this so I can read      from the same outFile

getline(inFile, bitValues); //had to look up getline(), was not covered in class
// I just came up with this idea, is this Valid??????????

    int posisiton = 10;
while(posisiton >= 0)
{
    cout << bitValues[posisiton]; // I ever done something like this but It worked!
    posisiton--;
}


int pause;
cin >> pause;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you use stack? Or just vector to emulate stack? Using a file for temporary storage seems to be an overkill.

Comment: I dont know what stack is, which means no. Vector definitely not. He said only using only those concepts because that's what we learned so far. I dont think this is fair at this point in our learning. It seems it requires much more than what we covered to be done. And im only doing the integer part lol.

Comment: Well, there are two ways. Way #1: you can read the file from the end! Can you ask for it's length and read the last character, then the character before last etc.?

Comment: Way #2: you can obtain your digits not from the rightmost to the leftmost, but other way round, in the natural order, so that you can output them immediately. In order to do this, you have to answer 2 questions: (1) how to test if the i-th binary digit in the number is 1 or 0? (2) what is the biggest possible number of binary digits in a number? If you know the binary operations like `&` or `<<` (on integers, not on `cout`), the answer would be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to write a recursive function? By doing the recursive call before outputting the remainder (as opposed to afterwards), you will get the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

1) Forget the file  (I don't know how that was going to help.  Maybe you misunderstood the teacher).  Just write a simple function to reverse the string.

```
for(int i=0; i<bitValues.length()/2; ++i) {
    char t = bitValues[i];
    bitValues[i] = bitValues[bitValues.length()-1-i];
    bitValues[str.length()-1-i] = t;
}
```

2) Or instead of using modulo, use a flag to get the bits in order the first time.  This isn't code because it more directly relates to your homework, than a simple string reversal.

```
resize the string to be big enough to hold all the bits
set a mask to have a 1 in the 31st position
for each position in the string
    use `&` with the mask to find if it's a one or zero
    set the character depending on the bit
    shift the mask right one.
```

Comment: As this is a homework, it would be better to give just hints, not the ready solutions.

Comment: Yeah, I removed the code from the second half right after I posted.  First half is a general/common bit used all the time that doesn't directly relate to his assignment.  I can remove the code there too if people think it's too much.

Comment: The notation of subscript for string just saved got me to produce the correct out put.

Comment: Never mind, it only gave it to me for the 43 number. Not for others.

Comment: `int posisiton = 10;` should be `int position = bitValues.size()-1;`